# stop mouseleave function triggering when the cursor moves by a pixel even when still over element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little social nav that has a couple of scripts running for it, one changed a background colour and the other moves a left/right border to the element that the mouse is over. This works fine when you are very precise with your mouse movements but if the cursor moves by just a pixel and even though you are still over the element the mouseleave function is triggered for both scripts. If you then move another pixel the mouseenter is triggered again.

I don't know why mouseleave is triggered as you have not left the element yet?

This is the nav:

```
<ul class="social">
<li id="socialTitle"><h4><a href="#">We are social</a></h4></li>
<li id="socialLink1"><h4><a href="#">twitter</a></h4></li>
<li id="socialLink2"><h4><a href="#">facebook</a></h4></li>
<li id="socialLink3"><h4><a href="#">pinterest</a></h4></li>
</ul>
```

This is the script at deal with the background colour change:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#socialLink1").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#socialwrapper").each(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#4099FF");
    });
}),
$("#socialLink2").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#socialwrapper").each(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#3b5998");
    });
}),
$("#socialLink3").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#socialwrapper").each(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#C92228");
    });
}),
$("#socialLink1,#socialLink2,#socialLink3").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#socialwrapper").each(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#ed1165");
    });
})});
```

This is the script at deal with the movement of the left/right border. In the default state the first li has the borders and as you roll over each of the other li elements the borders moves to them, when you roll off it moves back to the first li.

```
$(window).load(function(){
// insert slider
$('ul.social').append('<div id="socialslider"></div>');

// initially reset
var left = "0";
var width = "235";
$('#socialslider').css({'left' : left, 'width' : width});

// sliding
$('ul li a').mouseenter(function(){
    var left = $(this).parent().position().left+1;
    var width = $(this).width()+30;
    $('#socialslider').stop().animate({
        'left' : left,
        'width' : width
    });
});

$('ul li a').mouseleave(function(){
    var left = "0";
    var width = "235";
    $('#socialslider').stop().animate({
        'left' : left,
        'width' : width
    });
});});
```

Comment: Trying to reproduce the problem fails for me... I see no `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` conflict. It seems to be working. But maybe some more code would help. Like what is `#socialwrapper`. Can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: I made one for you... Maybe you could complete it. See here : https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/aLrkL4ry/

Comment: i rewrote your fiddle and it seems to run great, take a look on it and if you have any questions, i may also write a better awnser. https://jsfiddle.net/ooy4no1p/2/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I have uploaded a stripped back version of my page [here](http://cucodigital.co.uk/testing/index-slim.html). Safari/Chrome have the issue as outlined above, Firefox is even worse.

Comment: @DanielPfisterer using your example how would you target the ul, each link would give it a different colour - you can see from my link in the previous comment what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @CuCo I would do something like this: http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/zBNqZm

Comment: @DanielPfisterer so what in our code was causing the stutter (mouseleave being triggered whilst still over element? As it still stutters when the left/right border moves between elements in the example [here](http://cucodigital.co.uk/testing/index-slim2.html). Your implementation of the colour change works fine if I comment out the other code that deals with the left/right border sliding.

Comment: @CuCo, the mouseleave is caused by z-index, the element which contains the borders is placed over the listitems. And a div also should not be a child of an "UL". take a look on this updated example: http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/zBNqZm

Comment: @DanielPfisterer thanks for the help. I've merged that into [my own code](http://cucodigital.co.uk/testing/index-slim3.html) and it almost works perfectly. Only issue is that the default state & the rollover state on the first li element for 'left' are off by 4px when they should be identical. I have fixed the 'width' by hard coding that figure for the initial load but can't do the same for 'left' as that figure is dynamic. This happens in Safari/Chrome, FF is working fine.

I thought that lines 5 and 22 in your codepen may not target exactly the same element once it's been added to my code.

Comment: @DanielPfisterer never mind. Fixed that by just taking the a tag of the first element as it doesn't really need it there. Thanks for your help.